# Virtual properties with count = 0 are null

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing, entity-framework-5, in-memory-database

I'm using Effort (https://effort.codeplex.com/) which is a "ADO.NET provider that executes all the data operations on a lightweight in-process main memory database instead of a traditional external database" together with Nmemory.

Unfortunately if I execute my unit test with effort all virtual collection properties of my models with count = 0 are null.

Let me give you an example from the debugger:

This is how my object of my model looks after loading it with Effort inside the unit test:
[image: Object of model with Effort- properties are null]
This is how it looks like outside the real application without Effort:
[image: Object of model in real application- properties are not null]

This is how I initialize my "db connection" with Effort in unit test:

```
DbConnection connection = Effort.DbConnectionFactory.CreateTransient();
unitOfWork = new SqlUnitOfWork(connection);
```

My SqlUnitOfWork constructor called in the code above:

```
public SqlUnitOfWork(DbConnection connection)
{
    this.SetConnectionString();
    this.Context = new SqlContext(connection);
}
```

My SqlContext constructor called in the code above:

```
public SqlContext(DbConnection connection) : base(connection, true)
{
    this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
}
```

This is how my DbContextConfiguration looks like when the test runs:

[image: DbContextConfiguration]

So lazy loading is enabled. But not working correctly.

Comment: What if you set your class constructor with `CompanyComments = new List<Comment>();` ?

Comment: Where do you get the `company` from in your unit test? Do you create it with `new Company...`?

Comment: I get it from my unit of work and in unit test the unit of work connection is based on the in-memory-database.